# ¿Por qué en java no se puede escribir un while(false), pero sí se puede el contrario while(true)?

Tags: java

Da igual lo que introduzca, que da error.

```
while (true) {
        try {
              String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce un número entero:");
              if (input == null) { // Si el usuario cancela, devuelve 0
                return 0;
            }
            return Integer.parseInt(input);
          }    catch (NumberFormatException e) {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ha insertado letras en vez de números");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! porque, basicamente, que esperas que haga un while(false)

Comment: Si se puede escribir y funciona como es de esperarse. El `while` repite mientras la expresión evalúe como verdadero. Si pones `false` evalúa como falso y no se ejecuta.

Comment: @Mateo ¿Lo has probado? Al poner directamente "false" en lugar de una expresión el código no compila, se lanza una excepción en tiempo de compilación de "unreachable statement".

Comment: 1. Mayúsculas = GRITAR. 2. No era necesario el código; en todo caso, hubieras agregado un ejemplo con el while(false). Como te han dicho, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: @RubioRic no, nunca escribí `while (false)` así que no sabía que pasaba eso.

Answer (score 5):

No es más que una decisión tomada al diseñar el lenguaje. Y, como en otros muchos lenguajes, hay discusiones internas sobre cuestiones como éstas (si se debe mostrar únicamente un warning o lanzar un error).

En el caso de java, se sigue el criterio de que cada código debe tener un propósito. Por lo que, en el caso que comentas, el compilador te lanza un `unreachable statement` ya que el código no se va a ejecutar nunca.

Puedes leer más acerca de esto en el [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.22)

Comment: Recomiendo leer la documentación enlazada ya que explica por qué `while (false)` lanza un error y sin embargo `if (false)` lanza un warning.

Comment: También es interesante que `boolean b = false; while (b)` compila exitosamente pero si usamos `final boolean b = false;`, no.

Answer (score -3):

No es un tema de java, es un tema de cualquier lenguaje. Lo primero que hay que entender es como funciona la expresión condicional while.

```
while(mientras se complua esta condición como verdadera) {Ejecuta este código; }
```

Si de entrada le decimos que la condición es falsa como en :

```
while (false) { .... }
```

No hay ningún problema para el compilador, simplemente nunca se va a ejecutar por que la condición ya es falsa de entrada.

Un tema distinto es analizar el código que has puesto.

Comment: Puntualizo: en C++ y otros lenguajes la expresión while (false) no genera ningún problema, en Java usando el IDE netbeans genera un error `unreachable statement` , es decir, la declaración es inalcanzable y nunca se va a ejecutar.

Comment: Da igual el IDE que emplees, es el compilador javac el que da ese error. Es decir, SÍ es un tema de java y SÍ es un problema para su compilador.